# error: expected expression before 'book'

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm a stackoverflow browser, and I'm in my first C course. I've been working on some code for about a day now, for a school assignment. I'm supposed to be inserting a node into the middle of a linked list. As of right now, most of my code is compiling. I'm getting an error in the use of one of my declared functions:

```
bookshelves.c: In function ‘main’:
    bookshelves.c:53:14: error: expected expression before ‘book’
    print_shelf(book *head);
                ^~~~
bookshelves.c:62:14: error: expected expression before ‘book’
    print_shelf(book *head);
                ^~~~
bookshelves.c:66:14: error: expected expression before ‘book’
    print_shelf(book *head);
                ^~~~
```

I use the declared function three times in the code, but there's no error for declaration of the function. Nothing I found online was specific enough to help me out. I was thinking I might be using the wrong variable in the function declaration or something, but changing that only messes my code up more.

Here's the entirety of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct book_struct {
    char *titles;
    struct book_struct *next;
} book;

void print_node(book *next);
void print_shelf(book *head);

int main()  {

    book *A = malloc(sizeof(book));
    book *B = malloc(sizeof(book));
    book *C = malloc(sizeof(book));
    book *D = malloc(sizeof(book));
    book *E = malloc(sizeof(book));

    A->titles = malloc(20);
    B->titles = malloc(20);
    C->titles = malloc(20);
    D->titles = malloc(20);
    E->titles = malloc(20);

    strcpy(A->titles, "War and Peace");
    A->next = NULL;

    strcpy(B->titles, "War on Drugs");
    B->next = NULL;

    strcpy(C->titles, "War ");
    C->next = NULL;

    strcpy(D->titles, "War Horse");
    D->next = NULL;

    strcpy(E->titles, "War of 1812");
    E->next = NULL;


    book *shelf = A;
    A->next = B;
    B->next = C;
    C->next = D;
    D->next = E;
    E->next = NULL; // always remember to set "next" of the last book to NULL

    printf("Bookshelf before inserting new book:\n");
    print_shelf(book *head);

    {
    book new_book;
    strcpy(new_book.titles, "Twilight");
    new_book.next = NULL;

    C->next = &new_book;
    new_book.next = C;
    print_shelf(book *head);
    }

    printf("Bookshelf after inserting new book:\n");
    print_shelf(book *head);

    return 0;
}

void print_node(book *next)  {
    printf("%c\n", *next->titles);
}

void print_shelf(book *head)  {
    book *current = head;

    while (current != NULL)  {
        print_node(current);

        //Advance current
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

I've tried different things to fix the error, but nothing worked. Would appreciate some help with that error, you don't have to fix the entirety of the code. Once I get past this error I can go from there.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `print_shelf(book *head);` is an attempt to declare a function, not call one.

Comment: Oh, so do I remove the "*head" part of the code to fix that?

Comment: EDIT: changing the statements to print_shelf(book); does not fix the issue.

Comment: EDIT: changing it to print_shelf(head); fixes that issue but provides another one. "head" is now undeclared in the function (first use).

Comment: Nono you have to pass the name of the pointer to the `struct` whose title you want to print.

Comment: I mean what are you expecting the first `print_shelf(book *head);` to do?

Comment: @George I've corrected my linked list so that it says "book *head = NULL;", and that fixes that. Code compiles, I'll see if I can get it to work as expected after adding free(); for each node.

Comment: @George All of the print_shelf functions in int main() are supposed to print the entirety of the list (so effectively, the list without the node added in the middle, and the list with the middle node added is printed twice)

Comment: Ah right sorry, I was looking at the wrong function when I asked that. Anyway you want to be passing the `head` in this case `shelf` or `A`. And you only need to have one pointer to the head of your list, i.e. `b`, `c` etc... could be replaced with something like `book currNode = head; for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){ currNode->next = malloc(sizeof(book)); currNode = currNode->next;  } currNode->next = NULL; `

Comment: @George Are you saying I don't need the "A->next = B;" since I could have a function that declares that for each individual node?

Comment: Yes, that's what a linked list is and why it's useful, you can do anything you want with it using just the `head` pointer i.e. pass it, iterate it, add to it, remove from it etc...

Comment: Cool, i'll edit my original post to include the edits made. I'm currently getting errors with your function when I was getting no errors with the previous format. I changed the arrows to periods and that fixed most of it @George

Comment: `book currNode = head;` should of been `book* head = malloc(sizeof(book)); book* currNode = head;` From there, whenever you want to change or check something, you can just iterate the list.

Comment: @George I reverted the function back into my individual declarations for the sake of eliminating errors. I'm getting a reasonable result from the file execution, except I get a segmentation fault which I think I can fix on my own.

Comment: @George Thanks for your help! If you make an actual reply with your first response I'll use that as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your original error was incorrect calling syntax and could have been corrected by changing `print_shelf(book *head);` to `print_shelf(shelf)`. I've also re written your code to illustrate that linked lists are powerful and don't need individual pointers for each element outside of the elements themselves (I've excluded `free`ing the elements since the program would terminate right after anyway) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct book_struct {
    char *titles;
    struct book_struct *next;
} book;

void add_node(book* head, book* newNode);
void print_node(book *next);
void print_shelf(book *head);

char* titles[] = {"War and Peace", "War on Drugs", "War ", "War Horse", "War of 1812" };

int main()  {

    book* head = malloc(sizeof(book));

    {
        book* currNode = head;
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            currNode->titles = malloc(20); 
            strcpy(currNode->titles, titles[i]); // malloc is technically not neccessary here, just for consistancy with your original code :)
            currNode->next = malloc(sizeof(book));
            currNode = currNode->next;
        }
        currNode->titles = malloc(20); 
        strcpy(currNode->titles, titles[i]);
        currNode->next = NULL;
    }   

    printf("Bookshelf before inserting new book:\n");
    print_shelf(head);

    {
        book* new_book = malloc(sizeof(book));
        new_book->titles = malloc(20);
        strcpy(new_book->titles, "Twilight");
        new_book->next = NULL;

        add_node(head, new_book);
    }

    printf("Bookshelf after inserting new book:\n");
    print_shelf(head);

    return 0;
}

void print_node(book *next)  {
    printf("%s\n", next->titles);
}

void print_shelf(book *head)  {
    book *current = head;

    while (current != NULL)  {
        print_node(current);

        //Advance current
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void add_node(book* head, book* newNode) {
    book* current = head;
    while(current->next) current = current->next;
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You didn't have to do near this much. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

try for example

```
print_shelf(shelf);
```

passing a reference to an actual object of type `book` to your function.

Comment: I did "print_shelf(head);" and that worked. That's fine too, right? Given my function is "void print_shelf(book *head)"

Comment: in your main() function above you did not define a `book* head` variable to point to an object. But since your compiler didn't seem to complain, I think it's ok.